# Unable to find size of unsigned char string returned by solvable_lookup_bin_checksum() of libsolv library

Tags: c, binary, char, checksum, unsigned

I am trying to collect the binary checksum of a package using solvable_lookup_bin_checksum() of libsolv library. But I am not sure how to find the returned unsigned character string length as it contains binary data and it is not NULL terminated(Cannot use tradition string.c function).

Attaching my code snippet I am trying to copy the return string in other unsigned char string, but not able to get correct result because of length issue.

```
unsigned char *pszTemp = solvable_lookup_bin_checksum(pSolv, SOLVABLE_CHECKSUM, &checksumtype);
size_t pszTemp_size = strlen((const char*)pszTemp) + 1;
unsigned char *pszChecksum= (unsigned char *)calloc(pszTemp_size, sizeof(unsigned char));
memcpy(pszChecksum, pszTemp, pszTemp_size);
```

Let me know what you suggest how can we calculate the returned unsigned character string length.

Comment: `unsinged`? Please post real code.

Comment: This is a real code only, please pardon for spelling mistake. unsinged is a typo, please refer it as unsigned

Comment: @shivani, "it is not NULL terminated" and "how can we calculate the returned unsigned character string length." -->  In C, a _string_ is **always** _null character_ terminated, else it is not a string.  `unsigned char *pszTemp` is not a "return string".  It is a pointer.  It points to a byte.  The length of bytes it points to is not part of `pszTemp`.  Some other source of information is needed for the _length_.  Current posted code lacks context to know what length is.

Comment: The size is a fixed value for each checksumtype